# How to do gradle resource filtering

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I'm developing a java web application using gradle. I want to test this application in different environment such as local, test site or live. I have an idea to replace the variable on properties file based on environment. Assume this web application is running on test site. Here is my code.

build.gradle

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.*
import groovy.swing.*

if(!hasProperty("profile")) {
    ext.profile = "test"
}

if(!hasProperty("deployTarget")) {
    ext.deployTarget = "local"
}

if(deployTarget == "local") 
{
    apply from: "gradle-properties/local.properties"
}
else if(deployTarget == "test") 
{
    apply from: "gradle-properties/test.properties"
}
else if(deployTarget == "live") 
{
    apply from: "gradle-properties/live.properties"
}

processResources {
    from('src/main/resources') {
        include '*.properties'
        filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: ['serverEnvironment': serverEnvironment])
    }
}
```

gradle-properties/test.properties

```
ext.serverEnvironment="test"
```

src/main/resources/web.application.config.properties

```
server.environment=@serverEnvironment@
```

TestRestController.java

```
@RestController
public class TestRestController {

    @Resource //tested @Inject also
    private Environment environment;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test")
    public String testController() {
        return environment.getProperty("server.environment");
    }
}
```

I'm getting "local" result from these code. Am I missed something important? Please advice, thanks a lot.

Comment: I guess `hasProperty("deployTarget")` is false. Add `println serverEnvironment` just before `processResources` to check the value of `serverEnvironment` and thus determine which `gradle-properties` file has been loaded.

Comment: Also, `processResources { expand(serverEnvironment: serverEnvironment) }` is the new, easier way to replace tokens. Be aware though that it replaces placeholders like `${serverEnvironment}`, not `@serverEnvironment@`.